# If $X, Y$ are topological spaces, does $A \times B$ closed in $X \times Y$ imply $A$ closed in $X$ and $B$ closed in Y?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X, Y$ are topological spaces, and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$. Does $A \times B$ being closed in the product space  $X \times Y$ (with the product topology) imply that $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if neither of $A,B$ is empty. If one of the two is empty, the other can however be arbitrary, since $A\times \varnothing = \varnothing = \varnothing \times B$. This does not even require the Hausdorff property. For subsets $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$, we always have

$$\overline{A\times B} = \overline{A}\times \overline{B}.\tag{1}$$

On the one hand, since

$$(X\times Y) \setminus (C\times D) = (X\setminus C)\times Y \cup X \times (Y\setminus D),$$

the product of two closed sets is closed, so $\overline{A\times B} \subset \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$. On the other hand, if $(x,y) \in \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$, and $U$ is any neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ in the product topology, then there are neighbourhoouds $V$ of $x$ and $W$ of $y$ with $V\times W \subset U$. So there are $\xi \in V\cap A$ and $\eta \in W\cap B$, and hence $(\xi,\eta) \in (V\times W)\cap (A\times B) \subset U\cap (A\times B)$, which shows $(x,y) \in \overline{A\times B}$.

Now, if $A\times B \neq \varnothing$ is closed, then from $(1)$ we obtain

$$A\times B = \overline{A\times B} = \overline{A}\times \overline{B},$$

and from that follows $\overline{A} = A$ and $\overline{B} = B$.